# how to Omit weekends dates from the list of date between two dates in excel

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula, array-formulas

I have a list of date for the complete month generated by the formula =IF(ROWS($A$10:A10)>DAY(B$5),"",$B$4+ROWS(A$10:$A10)-1) where B4 is the start date and B5 is the end date I got the list of dates but I want to exclude the weekend Saturday and Sunday from the List.

Please Help me to sort out this issue.

Comment: Networkdays.intl() does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one has Office 365 put this in the first cell:

```
=WORKDAY.INTL(B4-1,SEQUENCE(NETWORKDAYS.INTL(B4,B5)))
```

And it will spill the results.

[image: ![enter image description here]

If not then put this in the first cell and copy down:

```
=IF(ROW($ZZ1)>NETWORKDAYS.INTL($B$4,$B$5),"",WORKDAY.INTL($B$4-1,ROW($ZZ1)))
```

[image]

Comment: =IF(ROW($ZZ1)>NETWORKDAYS.INTL($B$4,$B$5),"",WORKDAY.INTL($B$4,ROW($ZZ1)-1))  This formula work excellent but only one problem is that if the start date in B4 is weekend its should ignore it, currently it's taking the start date same as in the begning of result.

Comment: Thanks Scott, now I am trying to call data through Vlookup from this date list which i got through your given formula , now it's not working

Comment: Remember that the data type this produces is a double that is formatted as a date, If your data is a string that looks like a date, they will not match.

Comment: Also if this answered the question you put forward please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First row:  =$B$4+max(0,2-mod($B$4,7))

Rest of rows:  =PrevRow + max(1,3-mod(PrevRow+1,7))

You can add your IF test on $B$5

[image]